# Transactional Email: How to customize shipping address variable/html {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, email, email-templates, address

I am customizing Magento's transactional emails and am trying to remove the Telephone/Fax from displaying in the email as they are displaying as:

> T:-
>   F:-

The transactional mail template for new orders in the CMS is calling:

`{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}`

Which is defined in the top of the (cms based) email template as:

`"var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address"`

I don't quite understand what the purpose of this 'variable' definition is, but I also see no reference to this in the `sales.xml` file.

Does anyone know how to adjust this html? Is there a clear methodology for finding where things are defined/pulled from in Magento? I am clearly confused coming from working primarily with Wordpress theming.

--

*Apologies for the endless string of transactional email questions. Hopefully this will help build the beta stack exchange as a valuable resource :)*

Comment: No apologies necessary - I, for one, am glad to help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually the variables defined at the top of the email are 'injected' when the template is called. In this case it's the `order` object.

If you check out the file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` you can find around the line 948 the method `getShippingAddress`. This is the actual function you're referencing here.

Now for the `format('html')` part, this is where you can actually start making some changes. And the best part is, no coding is required.

Go to your backend `System > Configuration > Customer configuration > Addresslayout` and look for the field `HTML`. By default it will look like this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}} {{if city}}{{var city}}  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}} {{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

As you can see removing telephone and fax altogether is just a matter of deleting the last 2 lines before the VAT line.

Comment: Ah, this is amazing, thank you. I'm also amazed at how you can keep track of where everything is in Magento, it really takes a lot of time to understand your way around things. **I had one quick question**, is there a way to affect these `if` and `depend` statements with any logic? (eg: `if fax="-"`) Or what are these statements called?

Comment: From what I can tell [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21534/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements) maybe it isn't really possible?

Comment: hm no I don't think so. It's just simple conditions without much logic. But if it is possible please share :)

Comment: your mention of order.php really helped me on the issue thank you so much