# Adding shipping address in sales notification email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, transactional

I am trying to add shipping address to the default Magento sales notification email but the list of variables that I get after pressing "insert variable" does not have shipping address as a variable.

How do I go about adding this as a variable? I am new to Magento and it will be great is someone can tell me how does this email get triggered? There are methods in Order.php that get accessed but which code really calls those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article might help you customising the email templates. Especially section on adding dynamic content to templates will help you work out how to get shipping address in the template.
[Customizing Magento email templates](http://www.srikanth.me/magento-customizing-email-templates/)

Or a variable like

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
```

might just get you the shipping address in the template, as mentioned in a 
[similar post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/transactional-email-how-to-customize-shipping-address-variable-html-var-order)